# $http.get(url for my function in index.php) returns 404 error when callin my slim php function

Tags: php, angularjs, routes, slim

I am getting a 404 response when I use `$http.get` to fetch the list of users from my backend API, which is built using Slim.

This is my AngularJS method to call

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('api/getuser.php/getUser').success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
  });
}
```

This is my Slim route, located in `getuser.php`:

```
 $app = new Slim();
 $app->get('/getUser', 'getUser');
 $app->run();

 function getUser() {
     $sql = "select * FROM employees ORDER BY id";
     try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);   
        $wines = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($wines);
         } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text":"'. $e->getMessage() .'"}}'; 
        }
    }
```

Thanks for replies in advance:)

Comment: try to change `$http.jsonp` to `$http.get`

Comment: sorry it is actually get giving me 404 not jsonp please consider my above edit :)

Comment: Maybe it's because you used relative address? Try using absolute instead

Comment: I have not used URL rewriting and it is  working as expected in other modules under index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to register a function instead of a string?

Try:

```
$app->get('/getUser', getUser);
```

http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/get/